# Create JSON Schema value dependency

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JSON schema I want to change by a dependency of one of the *values* of the JSON structure. For example if `{"foo":1}` also include `{"fooBar":"number"}` in the schema, resulting in `{"foo":"number", "fooBar":"number"}` but if `{"foo":2}` instead include `{"fooBar2":"bool", "fooBar3":"string"}` resulting in `{"foo":1, "fooBar2":"bool", "fooBar3":"string"}`. Is this possible.

I know how to make the inclusion of a key change the schema (code example from [here](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html)) but I cannot find any example on how this could be done using values. If this is even possible.

```
 {
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "credit_card": { "type": "number" },
    "billing_address": { "type": "string" }
  },

  "required": ["name"],

  "dependencies": {
    "credit_card": ["billing_address"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but it's a little complicated.  Below is the general pattern.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "enum": [1] },
        "fooBar": { "type": "number" }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "enum": [2] },
        "fooBar2": { "type": "boolean" },
        "fooBar3": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```